# How to make a linux computer act as a gateway behind a gateway to an other linux device

Tags: networking, routing, forwarding

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222054/how-can-i-use-linux-as-a-gateway

I based myself on this and can ping the other gateway which is 10.0.0.1, but even though this is the default gateway on computer A the request to the outside world are not forwarded further.

Say I have computer A with 2 interfaces:

```
wlp2s0b1: 10.0.0.100
enp1s0f0: 192.168.0.100
```

And computer B with:

```
eth0: 192.168.0.101
```

Now I can ping 10.0.0.1 but the traffic doesn't seem to go outside. I do not have access to any configuration on the device at 10.0.0.1

Route on device:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.100   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Route on gateway1:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0b1
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0b1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp1s0f0
```

Iptables gateway1:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 9841 packets, 3893K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    6   504 ACCEPT     all  --  enp1s0f0 wlp2s0b1  anywhere             anywhere            
    6   504 ACCEPT     all  --  wlp2s0b1 enp1s0f0  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 13103 packets, 1261K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```